# Can power failure rollback mysql innodb database of many days?

Tags: mysql, innodb, acid, data-loss

I have an application running on a x86 system with MySQL InnoDB database. This application store many rows per day and yesterday, due to a power failure, I experienced a rollback of a one **entire** day of data. Simply I have a hole of data of the day before the power failure, and I'm sure there were many data before the power failure because I checked backup dumps.

How can a power failure involving data committed and so many rows? Is because of the log structure of innodb? Can I do something in MySQL configuration (expect to avoid power failure)?

My configuration is a standard-default of the mysql installer in Windows x64 7 environment.

Comment: What is your machine's configuration? What is the OS? Load on your system? Lots more detail required if we are even going to attempt an answer! Caching occurs at many levels in IT systems - database, OS, disk arrays. Although, I have to say that losing an entire **day's** data is rather a lot! Are there some batch processes in the background?

Comment: I edited the question with some informations, there is no batch, scheduled and so on. What I'm scarried about is the windows automatical restore after a configuration failure. Can this rollback the innofb log file? For this reason I moved the mysq data path away from c:\programData to a custom path c:\mysqldata. But it was not enough

Comment: Did you do anything to recover from the failure?  Or it simply powered up on its own?

Comment: Are all your tables `InnoDB`?  What are the values for `%sync%` and `innodb%`?

Comment: The user simply powered on the pc, and then found data loss, all tables are innodb. I cannot connect to use db to get that values, but they should be the default for mysql standard community installer for version 5.6.26

Comment: Please provide the mysql error log and configuration file related to innodb. If OS restored the older data folder, file missing error should logged in error log file.

Comment: I found that the problem is IBD file restoration from previous version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure that the rollback was made by automatic **Windows 7 System Restore** after the power failure. This restored the mysql data folder. I cannot understand how a OS restore can move files from other applications even becuse I was using a custom path for mysql-data: `c:\mysqldata` and not the standard `c:\programData\Mysql\...`.
My solution is to disabled the windows restore, but I think can be a better solution.

**EDIT**

The problem is the IBD data files of Mysql/MariaDB, these are a "monitored extension" and Windows rollbacks them anywhere in the volume.

**EDIT2**

Seems that switching innodb_file_per_table option to OFF solved the problem because new tables (only new ones) will not use IBD files.

Comment: Ouch!  This makes Windows a really _bad_ OS for running a database??

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: Incredulity....

Comment: @Tobia Does this apply also for windows 10 ? or only 7 ?
Thanx u help so

Comment: I guess it is the same for Win10, but I did not test it yet.