# Innodb switch innodb_file_per_table to OFF

Tags: index, innodb, restore, mariadb

I want to switch off the inno variable: innodb_file_per_table
I found that this affects only new tables, how to apply this change also to old tables? I tried:

Alter table (`ALTER TABLE xxx ENGINES=innodb`), but it doesn't work

I may dump everything and restore the entire DB but if possibile I want to avoid this procedure.

Answer (score 1):

What version are you using?  What makes you say it "doesn't work"?

Please note that `ibdata1` will *not shrink* during the process.  Only a dump and restore can fix that -- with a deletion of the `ibdata1` file in the middle.  But note...  Unless you tweak the dump, the load will be all-or-none (file_per_table or not).

I recommend changing only "large" files (over a few MB) to file_per_table.  Why?  With "tiny" tables, there is overhead of opening the `.ibd` files that, though small, might cancel out the benefits of file_per_table.

The 80-20 rule says that 20% of your tables take 80% of the disk space.  So another way to pick "large" is to pick the largest 20% of the tables.

In the future (version 8.0), I am looking toward tablespace-per-database as minor recommendation for tiny tables.

Comment: Doesn't work means that IBD files per table are still mandatory to work with table. This is the version: Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.18-MariaDB. I have to switch to innodb_file_per_table not for performance but to avoid windows restore IBD file deletion (see this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187500/can-power-failure-rollback-mysql-innodb-database-of-many-days). With innodb_file_per_table=0 seems that innodb tables become win-restore safe because IBD file are not rollbacked.

Comment: Ouch.  OK, most of my answer does not apply to what you describe. (Anyway, I was thinking "turn on" when I answered.)